# Button Click inside update panel causes post Back

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I want to cause a page post back  when a button is clicked that is inside an update panel. 
I attach you my code. The button I want to cause the post back is the btnUpdate. My goal is when the operation completed inside the modal popup, the gridview which is outside the modal popup to be updated.
The major problem is that I have multiple content place holders inside the same modal popup and I want to run asynchronous.

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button  ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" style="display:none" /> 

              <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" PopupDragHandleControlID="Panel1" RepositionMode="None" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlpopup" 
TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
    DropShadow="true"   
 BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">

        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" BackColor="LightGray" style="display: none"
             CssClass="modalPopup" Width="650px" >
               <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" Visible="false" runat="server">
 <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" ValidationGroup="r" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="160px" CommandName="Update" 
                                          OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" Text="Save"  
                                          Visible="False" />

                                      <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" ValidationGroup="r" Height="30px" Width="160px" onclick="Button5_Click" Text="Save" 
                                          Visible="False" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>
                          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" Visible="false" runat="server">
                     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                     <ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btn1" ValidationGroup="a" runat="server" Height="30px" Width="160px" CommandName="Update" 
                                          OnClick="btn1_Click" Text="Save"  
                                          Visible="False" />
                     </ContentTemplate>
                     </asp:UpdatePanel>
                        </asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
              <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                        <%--Content that you want to update on Button1 or Button2--%>//write content that you want to update
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
//trigger asyn event of control and it's event 
                        <%--asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  events of control on which this content should update--%>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

for more information http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx